# Manage hundreds of product attributes in a simple way

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

For the type of products that I manage in my eCommerce I should create about 300 product attributes to create a complete technical sheet.
Is there a way to create feature in a product page tab, like: "Add item" to add only the attributes that affect that single product? it would be very difficult to keep a page with 300 fields legible.

Answer (score -1):

If I read your question correctly, you want to organize your products to only require specific attributes. 
If so then you can use Attribute Sets to create attribute templates for your products.

When you create a new product, you can define the attribute set so the product only uses that subset of attributes.

See:
https://amasty.com/blog/beginners-guide-on-magento-product-attribute-sets/
https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/catalog/attribute-set.html

Comment: Yes this is obvious. I was wondering if there was a way, a module, that would handle them as explained, unlike the native mode.